# How to remove the out of sync error while deploying React app to gcloud

Tags: reactjs, npm, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I have tried using npm install and aslo npm cli still getting the error as mentioned in the terminal window but still getting the same error.

```
= Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 =#
        #============================================================#
        File upload done.
        Updating service [default]...failed.
        ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build c79b1b5c-68fd-4d88-b9bd-540d7aed83e2 status: FAILURE
        npm ERR! code EUSAGE
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@8.12.0 does not satisfy ajv@6.12.6
        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's json-schema-traverse@1.0.0 does not satisfy json-schema-traverse@0.4.1
        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.9.5 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.3.6 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@1.0.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@1.0.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@1.0.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@1.0.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@1.0.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@1.0.0 from lock file
        npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@1.0.0 from lock file
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Clean install a project
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Usage:
        npm ERR! npm ci
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Options:
```

Can someone help with this. I am using react18

Comment: can you have a look the suggestions in this github [thread](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5125#issuecomment-1483714064)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `node-version: [16.x]` was bound to use `npm@8.x` witch causes this problems only on the deploy.

Added this command before everything else, to use `npm@7.x` and it solved the issue:

```yaml
run: npm install -g npm@7.x.x
```